# Is there any mustache template for adding logging or exception handling when generating spring boot api using swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mustache, swagger-codegen

I have searched for this template but couldn't find one.

Is there any editor to generate mustache template for spring boot.

Please let me know how to modify existing mustache template to suit requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the author of the template didn't write any logging features within the spring boot template you 
will have to modify the template yourself. Instructions on using the generator with local template files can be found here

[templates](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#modifying-the-client-library-format)

You will have to download the spring template folder and the according java class if you don't want to clone the complete codegen project.

Comment: can we add our own custom class using mustache template?

Comment: Yes you can create templates for supporting class files.

Comment: Could you please share a sample template to add custom java class like CustomException.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/notFoundException.mustache

Is a supporting file for the spring generator.
The SpringCodegen.java uses this file to generate the class.

Comment: Thank you for your help....I have modified above mustache file to have my own custom Exception class..but it is still creating NotFoundException file with my CustomException class inside it.
One more thing my final aim is to add my own Custom class like class which provides common utility code for database connection or centralized exception handling using custom class with @ExceptionHandler annotation
Please suggest.

Comment: You probably still have to modify the SpringCodegen.java to include your supporting file.